# JPA - inheriting classes with same field name cause exception in save

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

We have a base class - Base, with 3 inheriting classes - ChildA, ChildB, ChildC.
All the classes are jpa entities, using a discrimination column.

Both ChildA and ChildB have a field with the same name, and ChildC doesn't:

`private Long longField;` (It's nullable)

So when we try to save to the DB an ChildA instance:

`this.childARepository.save(new ChildA(...));`

We get the following exception:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'longField' in 'field list'
```

We can think of few workarounds, but non of them is very good in this case:

1) Put `longField` in Base - doesn't make sense, because ChildC doesn't need it.

2) Create another Base class for ChildA & ChildB - doesn't make sense from an abstraction perspective.

3) Give a different name in ChildA & ChildB - Tried it and it works, but we would prefer not to that because it has the same meaning...

Is there another solution to this issue? Maybe something we're missing?
Thanks!

Comment: So many unanswered questions here... 1) what sort of mapping are you using for the inheritance hierarchy? Table-per-class? Discriminator column? 2) I understand you don't *want* to, but have you tried some of your workarounds? Give the field a different name in ChildB and see what happens? In other words, are you sure it's because A and B have a field with the same name?

Comment: See my edit, but: 1) discrimination column 2) Yes, i tried changing the names and it solved the problem

Comment: You did not show the inheritance setup.  Why does the table being used for A not have the 'longfield'?  if it does, then the problem is with your mapping and how you have setup inheritance - show the mapping and how it specifies the tables involved with ChildA

Comment: Two recommendations; pick one: 1) map `longField` to different columns in the database. **Please note** that this does not mean you have to change the name of the field in the Java class. This makes more sense if `longField` is not *exactly* the same thing in both classes. 2) If `longField` **is** exactly the same thing in both classes, then make a `Base2` class that inherits from `Base1` and has `longField` in it. Then `ChildA` and `ChildB` inherit from `Base2` while `ChildC` inherits from the original `Base`.